# How to handle NextResponse and StreamingTextResponse by single API call in client component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, openai-api, vercel-ai

Here is the backend code for API route with two responses NextResponse and StreamingTextResponse in Next JS.

The StreamingTextResponse is from the Vercel AI SDK.

```
import { checkFreeApiLimit, incrementApiLimit } from "@/lib/api-limits";
import { checkSubscription } from "@/lib/subscription";
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import OpenAI from "openai";
import { OpenAIStream, StreamingTextResponse } from "ai";
const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  try {
    const { userId } = auth();
    const body = await request.json();
    const { messages } = body;
    if (!userId) {
      return new NextResponse("Unauthorized User", { status: 401 });
    }
    if (!openai.apiKey) {
      return new NextResponse("OpenAI API Key not configured.", {
        status: 500,
      });
    }
    if (!messages) {
      return new NextResponse("Messages are required.", { status: 400 });
    }

    const freeTrial = await checkFreeApiLimit();
    const isPro = await checkSubscription();
    if (!freeTrial && !isPro) {
      return new NextResponse("Free trial is expired.", { status: 403 });
    }

    const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      stream: true,
      messages,
    });

    if (!isPro) {
      await incrementApiLimit();
    }

    const stream = OpenAIStream(response);

    return new StreamingTextResponse(stream);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("CONVERSATION_ERROR", error);
    return new NextResponse("Internal Error", { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

And this is the Client Component code in which the API is called using `useChat`  hook import from vercel ai/react.
But the API only responded StreamingTextResponse, not the NextResponse.

I want both responses from API.

```
"use client";
import Heading from "@/components/Heading";
import { useChat } from "ai/react";
import { MessageSquare, SendHorizonal } from "lucide-react";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { FormEvent, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { Empty } from "@/components/Empty";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { UserAvatar } from "@/components/UserAvatar";
import { BotAvatar } from "@/components/BotAvatar";
import { useglobalProModal } from "@/hooks/ProModalProvider";
import { BeatLoader } from "react-spinners";

const ConversationPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const proModal = useglobalProModal();

  const {
    messages, input, isLoading, error, handleInputChange, handleSubmit, setInput,
  } = useChat({

    api: "/api/conversation",
    
    onFinish() {
      setInput("");
      router.refresh();
    },
  });

  console.log(error);

  const onSubmit = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("on submit");
    const userMessage = {
      role: "user",
      content: input,
    };
    console.log(e);
    console.log(userMessage);

    handleSubmit(e);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Heading
        title="Conversation"
        description="The most advanced AI chat model."
        icon={MessageSquare}
        iconColor="text-violet-500"
        iconBgColor="bg-violet-500/10"
      />
      <div className="px-4 lg:px-8">
        <div>
          <form
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
            className="border rounded-md w-full p-4 px-3 md:px-6 focus-within:shadow-sm flex gap-x-2"
          >
            <Input
              className="border-0 outline-0 focus-visible:ring-0 focus-visible:ring-transparent caret-indigo-600"
              disabled={isLoading}
              value={input}
              placeholder="Prompt..."
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
            <Button disabled={isLoading}>
              <SendHorizonal />
            </Button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div className="space-y-4 mt-4">
          {messages.length === 0 && !isLoading && (
            <Empty label="let's start the conversation." />
          )}
          <div className="flex flex-col-reverse gap-y-4">
            {messages.map((message) => (
              <div
                key={message.content}
                className={cn(
                  "p-8 w-full flex items-start gap-x-8 rounded-md",
                  message.role === "user"
                    ? "bg-white border border-black/10"
                    : "bg-muted"
                )}
              >
                {message.role === "user" ? <UserAvatar /> : <BotAvatar />}
                <p className="text-sm">
                  {isLoading && message.role !== "user" ? (
                    <BeatLoader size={5} className=" text-primary" />
                  ) : (
                    message.content
                  )}
                </p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ConversationPage;
```